# Cannot mine at synced block with Ethereum Wallet

Tags: go-ethereum, myetherwallet, ethminer

I have trouble with mining with Ethereum wallet.

It has own geth, and I have blockchain synchronized. Ethereum wallet is running, same as its geth.

However, ethminer is throwing

> "JSON-RPC problem. Probably couldn't connect. Retrying in 1..."

which, according to this topic ( https://www.cryptocompare.com/mining/guides/how-to-mine-ethereum/ ) means, that blockchain is actually not synchronized.

Also, I have my MyEtherWallet connected to Ethereum wallet via its json, if it has some role in this issue.

So please, any tips, how to get miner connected?

Thanks :)